# How to scroll to next div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to scroll down to next image, when someone click on "next". But my JS is not working.

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
       $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:$(this).parent().next().offset().top}, 'slow');

});
```

```css
.next {
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="next">next</a>


<div class="mainimages">
  <p style="margin-left:7px;"><strong id="imagetext"> Okay... </strong></p>
  <img src="images/5.png" alt="Image" style="width:100%">
  
<div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="like(this.id)"><div   type="image" class="like" style="vertical-align:middle">Like</div></a><span class="liken0 lik" id="liken0"></span></div>
  <div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="dislike(this.id)"><div  type="image" class="dislike" style="vertical-align:middle">Dislike</div></a><span class="disliken0 dislik" id="disliken0"></span></div>
<br> 
  <p style="margin-left:7px;"><strong id="imagetext"> Okay... </strong></p>
  <img src="images/5.png" alt="Image" style="width:100%">
  
<div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="like(this.id)"><div   type="image" class="like" style="vertical-align:middle">Like</div></a><span class="liken0 lik" id="liken0"></span></div>
  <div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="dislike(this.id)"><div  type="image" class="dislike" style="vertical-align:middle">Dislike</div></a><span class="disliken0 dislik" id="disliken0"></span></div>
    <br>
      <p style="margin-left:7px;"><strong id="imagetext"> Okay... </strong></p>
  <img src="images/5.png" alt="Image" style="width:100%">
  
<div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="like(this.id)"><div   type="image" class="like" style="vertical-align:middle">Like</div></a><span class="liken0 lik" id="liken0"></span></div>
  <div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="dislike(this.id)"><div  type="image" class="dislike" style="vertical-align:middle">Dislike</div></a><span class="disliken0 dislik" id="disliken0"></span></div>
    <br>
      <p style="margin-left:7px;"><strong id="imagetext"> Okay... </strong></p>
  <img src="images/5.png" alt="Image" style="width:100%">
  
<div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="like(this.id)"><div   type="image" class="like" style="vertical-align:middle">Like</div></a><span class="liken0 lik" id="liken0"></span></div>
  <div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="dislike(this.id)"><div  type="image" class="dislike" style="vertical-align:middle">Dislike</div></a><span class="disliken0 dislik" id="disliken0"></span></div>
    <br>
      <p style="margin-left:7px;"><strong id="imagetext"> Okay... </strong></p>
  <img src="images/5.png" alt="Image" style="width:100%">
  
<div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="like(this.id)"><div   type="image" class="like" style="vertical-align:middle">Like</div></a><span class="liken0 lik" id="liken0"></span></div>
  <div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="dislike(this.id)"><div  type="image" class="dislike" style="vertical-align:middle">Dislike</div></a><span class="disliken0 dislik" id="disliken0"></span></div><br>
      <p style="margin-left:7px;"><strong id="imagetext"> Okay... </strong></p>
  <img src="images/5.png" alt="Image" style="width:100%">
  
<div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="like(this.id)"><div   type="image" class="like" style="vertical-align:middle">Like</div></a><span class="liken0 lik" id="liken0"></span></div>
  <div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="dislike(this.id)"><div  type="image" class="dislike" style="vertical-align:middle">Dislike</div></a><span class="disliken0 dislik" id="disliken0"></span></div><br>
      <p style="margin-left:7px;"><strong id="imagetext"> Okay... </strong></p>
  <img src="images/5.png" alt="Image" style="width:100%">
  
<div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="like(this.id)"><div   type="image" class="like" style="vertical-align:middle">Like</div></a><span class="liken0 lik" id="liken0"></span></div>
  <div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="dislike(this.id)"><div  type="image" class="dislike" style="vertical-align:middle">Dislike</div></a><span class="disliken0 dislik" id="disliken0"></span></div><br>
      <p style="margin-left:7px;"><strong id="imagetext"> Okay... </strong></p>
  <img src="images/5.png" alt="Image" style="width:100%">
  
<div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="like(this.id)"><div   type="image" class="like" style="vertical-align:middle">Like</div></a><span class="liken0 lik" id="liken0"></span></div>
  <div style="float:left;" ><a id="0" class="no" onClick="dislike(this.id)"><div  type="image" class="dislike" style="vertical-align:middle">Dislike</div></a><span class="disliken0 dislik" id="disliken0"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have lot to work with. `$(this)` will return `html,body`, and these don't have `parent` (at least `html`). I think you had a next button in each article. But decided to move it to a fixed position (for better UX). You have to keep track of active image, and hold its jQuery object to a variable. then select its next, and scroll to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, alternative for your js code

```
var imgs = $('.mainimages img');
imgs.attr('id', function(index) {
    return 'img'+ index;
});

var i = 0;
$(".next").click(function() {

   $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#img' + i).offset().top}, 'slow');
   i++;
   if (i == imgs.length) {
    i = 0;
   }
});
```